# Using 'font-weight: lighter' or 'font-weight: 100' reliably across email clients

Tags: html, email, fonts, font-family

---

I have a headline that I am trying to make with `font-family: helvetica neue; font-weight: 100;` which looks great on the web version but appears `font-weight: normal;` in most email clients.

I am working within Hubspot to send these emails.

```
    <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class="headlineOne" style="color: #000000; font-family: helvetica 
    neue, 
    helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 100; font-size: 44px; text-
    align: left; line-height: 44px;">It's never too early</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="headlineTwo body-text" style="line-height: 41px; margin-top: 
    0; font-size: 41px; text-align: right; font-weight: 200; padding-
    right: 99px; font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-
    serif; color: #4a4646; padding-bottom: 0px;">to start saving</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Define reliably, keeping in mind that all browsers and user agents display CSS and HTML to their own interpretation based on the W3C spec. It's impossible to test all possible user agents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helvetica Neue is not a web-safe font so what you're seeing in most email clients is Helvetica. To use Helvetica Neue, you'll need to use @import or link to create a link in the `<head>` to make it work in email. You'll also need to link to a webfont.

Even with the webfont, Helvetica Neue will not work in Gmail or Outlook. Gmail does not support webfonts and Outlook seems to ignore fonts with a space in the name.

You've discovered the issue with using Helvetica as a backup font for Helvetica Neue which is the fonts have different dimensions, so you will get a different look when you view the email in two different clients, like Apple Mail and Gmail.

If you use `Font-weight: 100;` the lightest weight Neue is not going to look the same as Helvetica. If that variation does not affect the layout of your email then use Helvetica as your fallback. Otherwise try another websafe font that might better match your needs. As an example, Lucida Grande, Trebuchet MS might be a better fallback font.

For more information, check out this links:

**The Ultimate Guide to Web Fonts**

- https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts

Other helpful resources:

- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-weight/
- https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/neue-helvetica/webfont_preview.html
- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp
- https://websitesetup.org/web-safe-fonts-html-css/

Good luck.